# my mail can't be sent anymore?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My mail was sent without problem when I runserver but when I added the last two lines in views.py the e-mail can't be sent anymore .
/newsite/mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render 

def send(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a  depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['yyyyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com'])

        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('send_mail')

    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mail/index.html', {})
```

/newsite/mail/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 url(r'^$', views.send, name='send'),
]
```

/newsite/newsite/settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='xxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Could you add the `mail/index.html` file please ?

Comment: it's a simple html file <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alert</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  l'alerte est envoyé à votre client 
  </body>
</html>

Comment: What are the lines you added? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I have just added def index(request): return render(request, 'mail/indexhtml' , {}) !!!!! I don't get any error

Comment: ah I see. In you question you wrote "added two lines in html". This was confusing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `urlpatterns`. Your are using the same regex/url for `index` and `send`. Change the url of `send`.

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 url(r'^send-mail/$', views.send, name='send'),
]
```

Now the mail should be send when you access `/send-mail/`

Comment: when I  run it it sends at least 5 mails and it shows this error "the page is not redirected correctly  " . My  goal is when  the mail  is sent a page can be shown in order to inform that  the message is sent ! I didn't know how to make it

Comment: You are trying to redirect to `send_mail`. But this does not exist. Try this: `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`

Comment: Thankyou for your help it works now ^_^ ! but may  i ask you how can I let the html file appears instantly when the mail sent I mean when I access to /mail/send_mail the mail will be sent and in the saame time the page html appears showing that the msg sent

Comment: You're welcome. About the other question. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429708/dont-freeze-on-sending-mail-django/35430555#35430555